# Possible to add an EventListener to a function for Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, preprocessor, aop

I'm trying to setup something like Aspect Oriented Programming in Actionscript 3, basically the only thing I need to be able to do is something like this:

```
SomeClass.getMethod("methodName").addEventListener(afterMethodExecuted, function() {
    //run code
});
```

This way I can run code after (or before) any method in any class has run, allowing numerous new possibilities.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a wrapper on a method. The [BindUtils](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) class of the Flex library does just that using the [ChangeWatcher](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html). It does so by wrapping a property but in ActionScript a method is just a property.

I suggest reading the code for those methods ($FLEX_ROOT/sdks/4.0.0/frameworks/projects/framework/src/) to get an idea of how you can do the same.

You might also be interested in the [FunctionReturnWatcher](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/binding/FunctionReturnWatcher.as).

Comment: Note that the given method should be updated for all instances if I give a class rather than an object (class instance). Do the classes you linked work like that?

Comment: As far as I can tell the classes I linked will not do that. You can probably wrap the class constructor in a similar method to ensure that each instance it creates is wrapped. (I hope that makes sense - have a look here http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html#constructor to see how to overwrite the constructor of an Object)

Comment: This will probably cause a significant loss of performance though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by performance loss. Each instance will have to call one extra function when it is instantiated, so I guess you'll be paying for a stack-frame. That should be the only issue since Flash already does dynamic dispatch on all function calls (AFAIK)